# Trying to count the rows in a data.frame after removing NA's using na.omit()

Tags: r

I'm new to programming and trying to count the number of rows in a file after removing the NA values. The function should return a data frame where the first column is the name of the file and the second column is the number of complete cases.

Here is my code:

```
complete <- function(directory, id = 1:332){
  setwd(directory)

  df <- data.frame()
  for (i in seq_along(id)){
    if (id[i] < 10){ 
    file_name <- paste("00",id[i],".csv", sep = "")
  }
    else if (id[i] >= 10 & id[i] < 100){
    file_name <- paste("0",id[i],".csv", sep = "")
  }
    else{
    file_name <- paste(id[i],".csv", sep = "")
  }
    file <- read.csv(as.character(file_name))
    newfile <- na.omit(file)
    #print(newfile)

    df <- data.frame(id = id, nobs = nrow(newfile))

  }

    print(df)

}
```

When I pass in a vector of 1:3 like so: complete("specdata", 1:3) I'm getting the following output:

```
id    nobs
1     243
2     243
3     243
```

Where id is the file number of files listed 1 to 332 and nobs equals the number of complete cases.

It seems as though it's taking the last item in my dataframe and repeating for each id and I don't know how to fix it. I get tripped up on programming logic like this being a beginner. Also, I saw a few other solutions to this problem but they were using complete.cases which I didn't understand how to apply. So each id in the data frame should have it's own count of complete cases (the nobs column in the data frame).

Comment: There is no way to reproduce your code so it is hard to anybody to understand the problem. However, I think you should replace this line `df <- data.frame(id = id, nobs = nrow(newfile))` by `df <- data.frame(id = i, nobs = nrow(newfile))`. a general suggestion: use `debug` so you can see step by step what is your function doing.

Comment: Also, maybe complete.cases makes more sense here? Not entirely sure.

Comment: the problem is not on `nrow(newfile)` but in `id=id`. review the previous comment.

Comment: Hi Carlos, I changed id to i, great catch. Now it returns the correct number of complete cases but only for that particular ID. If I pass it a vector I expect to get a number of complete cases for ID 1, 2 and 3 but it only gives me the last ID which is 3.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a shortened version to study from. Notice that I do not have to explicitly `paste` the zeroes since the files are already in order. Try `list.files(path="specdata", full.names=TRUE)` alone to see what that function does:

```
complete <- function(directory, id=1:332) {
  lst <- sapply(id, function(x) {
           df <- read.csv(list.files(path=directory, full.names=TRUE, pattern="csv")[x])
           sum(complete.cases(df))
  })
  data.frame(id,nobs=unlist(lst))
}
```

**edit**

Difference between `na.omit` and `complete.cases` are:

```
#Example
#Create data.frame with an NA value
df <- head(iris,3)
df[1,1] <- NA
df
#   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
# 1           NA         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
# 2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
# 3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa


#'na.omit' will return a data.frame with non-NA rows:
na.omit(df)
#   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
# 2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
# 3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa

#'complete.cases' gives TRUEs and FALSEs for the rows with NAs
complete.cases(df)
#[1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

I use 'complete.cases' because I just want the total count of non-NA rows. I don't need the data.frame itself, which is what 'na.omit' gives.

I can add up the TRUEs and FALSEs to get the total with `sum(complete.cases(df))`. The program will know to turn each `TRUE` into `1` and each `FALSE` into `0`.

Comment: Thank you Pierre, we haven't learned about the sapply function yet. That's in our next lesson. But I will study your code. Thanks again.

Comment: Also it seems that more people use the complete.cases function than na.omit. Is complete.cases more intuitive?

Comment: The two functions are similar, since they both search out for rows with at least one `NA` value. I added an example to highlight the difference.

Answer (score 0):

you have to make a couple of changes in your code...
first, define your data.frame in full extent at the beginning, before your loop.

```
df <- data.frame(id = id, nobs = NA)
```

second, after you create `newfile` replace your `df <- data.frame...` instruction with:

```
df[i,2] <- nrow(newfile)
```